# "This was the forest near Ingolstadt" in Frankenstein

Tags: meaning, frankenstein, mary-shelley

The following is a passage in Mary Shelley's *Frankenstein*. I am wondering what the boldfaced "This" refers to.

> Before, dark and opaque bodies had surrounded me, impervious to my touch or sight; but I now found that I could wander on at liberty, with no obstacles which I could not either surmount or avoid. The light became more and more oppressive to me, and the heat wearying me as I walked, I sought a place where I could receive shade. **This** was the forest near Ingolstadt; and here I lay by the side of a brook resting from my fatigue, until I felt tormented by hunger and thirst. This roused me from my nearly dormant state, and I ate some berries which I found hanging on the trees or lying on the ground. I slaked my thirst at the brook, and then lying down, was overcome by sleep.

Comment: The "place where I could receive shade".

Comment: @tgdavies Thank you. That was my first thought too. However, is this use of "this" acceptable in contemporary English? Consider the following passage, modeled on Shelley's:

Comment: At that time, I was in a strange place. As I was hungry, I was looking for an eatery. **This** was near an interstate highway and here I ate a jumbo burger and an order of French fries. I stayed there until I was refreshed and energized.

Comment: It will be interesting to see what people with a more formal understanding of the English language have to say, but to me this usage is absolutely acceptable in contemporary English -- written English at any rate. But I think the subject of "this" should be a bit more abstract. "I looked for a way to satisfy my hunger. This was an eatery just off the interstate". When Shelley uses it, it doesn't seem flowery, in fact it's very economical, but in "modern" writing I suppose it fits less well. I'd be tempted to say "This took the form of an eatery..." which I think is bad writing.

Comment: On reflection, I prefer "...satisfy my hunger. In an eatery just off the interstate, I..." Simpler.

Comment: @tgdavies please consider writing an answer, as you've already correctly answered the question in the comments. Thanks!

Comment: @verbose done, although I wonder whether some commentary on the formal grammar of the situation (which is beyond me as a completely idiomatic English speaker!) would improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "This" in the quotation refers to the "place where I could receive shade".

Think of it as "I wanted a place where I could receive shade" and "The place where I could receive shade was the forest near Ingolstadt."